# How to fix a xaml.cs indentation problem in WPF (Visual Studio 2019)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019, indentation

I am currently developing an application in **WPF (.NET Core)** and I'm encountering an indentation problem.

Here is the **App.xaml.cs** when I manually format it :

[image: App.xaml.cs]

When I go back to the line, my cursor goes here :

[image: App.xaml.cs cursor]

If I format the document (*Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D*) :

[image: App.xaml.cs auto-format]

I don't have this problem in **UWP**, and I don't know what to do to solve this problem. Here is an example of my cursor when I go back to the line in UWP :

[image: cursor example UWP]

**Options** -> **Text Editor** -> **C#** -> **Tabs** :

[image: C# options]

Thanks to those who will try to help me and sorry if my English isn't perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the chance of changing the indentation settings (among others) on a per-project basis by providing a `.editorconfig` file, that will override some settings in Visual Studio project. If you're having different behaviors on the same language but different projects, look for such a file and change the setting there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I created an .editorconfig file in my solution (because my solution contains several projects). It was pre-filled and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

You're changing the setting for XAML, but the code you show is C#. Try editing the C# settings instead.

Comment: Thank you ! For Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs, it's the same configuration.. and as I mentioned earlier, in UWP, the indentation is good. The options change from one project to another? (I edited my post)